# Why I can't see my error msg from apex in lightning component?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, aura, aura-handler

What is wrong here? I see only `Error` on toast.

```
    let toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");

    action.setCallback(this,function(a){
        let state = a.getState();      
        if(state == "SUCCESS"){
            ---------  //some actions
            toastEvent.setParams({
                title: "Success",
                message: "Congratulations!",
                type: "success"
            });
            toastEvent.fire();
        } else if(state == "ERROR"){
            let errors = a.getError();
            toastEvent.setParams({
                title: "Error",
                message: errors,
                type: "error"
            });
            toastEvent.fire();
        }
    });
```

Apex part:

```
} else{
    throw new AuraHandledException('You already have this record!');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ask the server's response for the actual message, rather than just passing the error object to your Toast event.

There are some great, thorough examples on the [Salesforce Developer Blog](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2017/09/error-handling-best-practices-lightning-apex.html). Here's their example of how to handle an error return via a Toast message, in a helper function:

```
handleErrors : function(errors) {
    // Configure error toast
    let toastParams = {
        title: "Error",
        message: "Unknown error", // Default error message
        type: "error"
    };
    // Pass the error message if any
    if (errors && Array.isArray(errors) && errors.length > 0) {
        toastParams.message = errors[0].message;
    }
    // Fire error toast
    let toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
    toastEvent.setParams(toastParams);
    toastEvent.fire();
}
```

The critical element is that they do

```
toastParams.message = errors[0].message;
```

to obtain the textual message that's supplied to the `AuraHandledException` in Apex. That's what you need to do here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have manage the correct error handling. Please make sure you Enqueue the action so that the framework processes it.

```
$A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Comment: I have that. Thank you)