# Custom message in AuraHandledException: is it possible?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, aura, aura-handler

How about situations, when I haven't Exception (it's not `try/catch`), but I still need to send a custom error message to the toast? When I try to use `throw new AuraHandledException('My custom msg here');` I get `FATAL_ERROR System.AuraHandledException: Script-thrown exception` in this case.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: You already asked [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/253539/why-i-cant-see-my-error-msg-from-apex-in-lightning-component) , hows this different ?

Comment: No. It was about exception's error.

Answer (score 20):

For reasons I don't understand, you have to invoke the `setMessage` method to output a custom message on the client-side:

```
    String m = 'My cusom msg here';
    AuraHandledException e = new AuraHandledException(m);
    e.setMessage(m);
    throw e;
```

Comment: I can still make following lines working (even as part of managed package):
       `} catch(Exception ex) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
        }`

Comment: It still looks like `state == "SUCCESS"` and green toast. But in `System.debug('Some error msg')` all is ok: I can see this error in debug.